# ServiceStack Redis Get an struct always return default

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm using ServiceStack Redis. I have an `struct` and I want to storage it in Redis. But when I try to get it, it always return the default value. **But if I change the `struct` for `class` it works ok**. Any ideas?

```
public struct PersonStruct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Unit test (It always pass, because redis return the default for the struct)

```
var obj = new PersonStruct() {Name = "SomeName", Year = 1235};
_redis.Set(key, obj, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
var result = _redis.Get<PersonStruct>(key);

Assert.AreEqual(default(PersonStruct), result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For structs you have to use custom serializer/deserializer

```
var obj = new PersonStruct() {Name = "SomeName", Year = 1235};
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj));

_redis.Set(key, bytes, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

var getBytes = _redis.Get(key);
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PersonStruct>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(getBytes));
```

Seems it's serializing structs by calling `ToString()`

Comment: What serializer are you using? I'm getting an error on: JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj) Im trying with Newtonsoft.

Comment: @satellitesatellite ```System.Text.Json;```

Answer (score 2):

The differences with Struct's is that they're [treated like a single scalar value](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#c-structs-and-value-types), where instead of serializing every property of a struct value, e.g. [Date, Day, DayOfWeek, DayOfYear, Hour, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1#properties) in the case of a DateTime, only a single scalar value is serialized for DateTime's, TimeSpan's, etc.

[ServiceStack.Text serializers does this by convention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#c-structs-and-value-types) where it will attempt to use `ToString()` to serialize into a single string value and the `TStruct(string)` constructor to deserialize the value. Alternatively you can provide your own deserializer function with a static `ParseJson()` method.

So if you want to deserialize structs you would need to provide a serializer/deserializer for your Struct by overriding `ToString()` and providing a string constructor, e.g:

```
public struct PersonStruct
{
    public PersonStruct(string jsonStr)
    {
        var str = jsonStr.FromJson<string>();
        Year = int.Parse(str.LeftPart(','));
        Name = str.RightPart(',');
    }
        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString() => Year + "," + Name;
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it in ServiceStack.Redis Typed APIs as seen in this [Gistlyn example gist](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=54e452bb1e86e132068a595d7e72d1a6).